# 405 Method Not Allowed when deploying artifact to Nexus

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I am deploying an artifact to a Nexus snapshot repository that allows redeployment, using the maven command:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=https://nexus.perque.com/repo/browse
/pont-aeri -DrepositoryId=tomcat-nexus.devops-snapshots -DgroupId=com.pont.aeri.pastis -DartifactId=pastis -Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=zip  -Dfile=D:\Users\pastis\IdeaProjects\pastis\pastis-web\target\pastis.war
```

but I have this error:

```
rds/0.0.2/pastis.zip 405 Method Not Allowed
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (Sin
```

Comment: Why are you trying to deploy a WAR with packaging `zip`?

Comment: I have the same problem packaging as a war

Comment: Is it just the redeploy that does work, or even when you are deploying for the first time? We also use Nexus at our company and that's similar to our browsing URL but not the one we use for deploying via maven. Also, can you access the log viewer in that nexus? Via interface is in administration -> Suppor -> Logging. It might have extra information.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have never seen a `mvn deploy:deploy-file` to a `nexus/repo/browse` URL: `browse` should not be used for deploying files, only for... browsing them.

A typical call would be

```sh
mvn deploy:deploy-file \
  -Dfile=/path/to/a/file \
  -Dpackaging=jar -DgroupId=<aGroup> -DartifactId=<anArtifactId> -Dversion=x.y.z-SNAPSHOT \
  -DrepositoryId=<repoId> \
  -Durl==https://nexus.perque.com/content/repositories/repos-snapshots/
```

(Replace `repos-snapshots` by the name you gave to the hosted snapshot repositories)

Answer (score 6):

405 Method Not Allowed, means the http method that your client is trying to call (probably POST) in this case, is not allowed. The url, probably is wrong to upload the artifats, https://nexus.perque.com/repo/browse . Could you please use snapshot url instead of https://nexus.perque.com/repo/browse? Guess it should be something like  repository/maven-snapshots/ .  https://mincong.io/2018/08/04/maven-deploy-artifacts-to-nexus/

Comment: In my case, I simply forgot to add `/repository` to the url. So I had to use `https://server/repository/reponame/dir/file` instead of `https://server/reponame/dir/file`.